# How can I submit a Spark Graphx job example on Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, spark-graphx

I created a cluster on Google Cloud Platform having five linux based virtual machines (VM): one master and 4 workers.
I ran `./start-master.sh` on the master VM and `./start-worker.sh [external-master-IP:7077]` on the worker VMs.

Now I want to simply *run a Graphx example job*, for example a PageRank algorithm that is already in Spark, using **./bin/spark-submit**.

I know, I read the documentation, which says to run like this:

```
./bin/spark-submit \
   --class <main-class> \
   --master <master-url> \
   --deploy-mode <deploy-mode> \
   --conf <key>=<value> \
   ... # other options
   <application-jar> \
   [application-arguments]
```

And I tried this:

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class org.apache.spark.examples.graphx.PageRankExample \
  --master spark://<external-IP>:7077 \
  --deploy-mode cluster
```

And it says:

> " Error: Missing application resource. "

Do I need to add a .jar? I can't find it for this PageRank example.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to add the jar in the spark-submit command :

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class org.apache.spark.examples.graphx.PageRankExample \
  --master spark://<external-IP>:7077 \
  --deploy-mode cluster
  ../examples/jars/spark-examples_[your version].jar
```

You should find it in the `examples/jars` folder under the spark installation. The jar is named `spark-examples_*.jar`:

[image]